# AttributeError Python Crash Course

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am following Python Crash Course to create the Alien Invasion game. I am quite confused about one call in the `run_game()` method. In the book it is mentioned that "When you call `update()` on a group, the group automatically calls `update()` for each sprite in the group. The line `self.bullets.update()` calls `bullet.update()` for each bullet we place in the group bullets."

I try to insert a `self.bullets.draw_bullet()`call into the `run_game()` method but end up with AttributeError:

> 'Group' object has no attribute 'draw_bullet'.

Why is it? Should the group automatically calls `draw_bullet()` for each sprite in the group? Why '`draw_bullet()`' is different from '`update()`'? Could someone shed some light? Thank you.

Here is the original code from the book, which is working.
alien_invasion.py

```
import sys, pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assests and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self.bullets.update()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:                                    
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        new_bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_screen(self):
        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
```

bullet.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color

        # Create a bullet rect at (0,0) and then set correct position
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width,
            self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midtop = ai_game.ship.rect.midtop

        # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bullet(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Comment: If I look at it quick, it seems like you're using the following line: for bullet in self.bullets.sprites(), but you should check: for bullet in self.bullets. Otherwise you're not checking the bullets class to see if there is a draw_bullet function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `bullets` has no attribute `draw_bullet`.

`bullets` is an instance of [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), but `Bullet` is derived from [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) object. An instance of `Bullet` has a method `draw_bullet`, because you've implemented it.

If you want to draw each bullet then you've to traverse the bullets and call `draw_bullet` for each bullet:

```py
for bullet in selfbullets:
    bullet.draw_bullet()
```

The other option is to use the [`.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) method of the `pygame.sprite.Group`. In this case `Bullet` has to have the attributes `.rect` and `.image`, but it doesn't need any draw method (`draw_bullet`) at all, because `draw()` uses the attributes of each bullet to draw them. e.g.:

```py
class Bullet(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color

        # Create a bullet rect at (0,0) and then set correct position
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width,
            self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midtop = ai_game.ship.rect.midtop

        # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

        # create Surface 
        self.image = pygame.Surface(self.rect.size)   # <-----
        self.image.fill(self.color)                   # <-----

    def update(self):
        self.y -= self.settings.bullet_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

```py
self.bullets.draw()
```

Comment: I see why `bullets` has no attribute of `draw_bullet`. Now the question is why `bullets` has the attribute of `update`. In the `run_game()` method, there is a call `self.bullets.update()`. Why no error pops up?

Comment: It makes sense now. Thanks much for the answer.